# What happened to Tanha, Raga and Arati?

Tags: enlightenment

Was re-watching the movie "[Thus have I heard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0tyQ6lLuP8)" and started to ponder about the 3 daughters of Mara? What happened to Tanha, Arati and Raga after they failed to enamour the Buddha post his enlightenment? Did they die and if they did, where were they reborn? Is there any information about them in the texts? Can someone please shed light.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It seems like a simple request for academic information. What transgression was imagined?

Comment: If it is a simple request, why don't you offer an answer? Thanks

Comment: A relevant sutta is [SN 4.25](https://suttacentral.net/sn4.25/en/sujato) (perhaps I can rewrite this as an answer later, several days from now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the Buddha attained enlightenment, Mara sent his three daughters to tempt the Buddha and prevent him from reaching the final goal which Buddha was very close to attaining. The three daughters of Mara are Tanha **(desire)**, Raga **(lust)**, and Arati **(aversion)**.

Mara becomes a representation for internal vices. His attack on the Buddha represents internal impulses towards violence and rage that can be overcome by following the Buddha's teachings of cultivating compassion, detachment and gentleness.

The daughters of Mara represent lust, desire and aversion, which the Buddha overcame by recognizing their true nature as emptiness. Mara's own attack on the Buddha's pride was defeated by the Buddha's denial of the self since there was no "I" (ego) left to feel pride.

Thus, the story of Mara's temptation can be interpreted symbolically there is no death or rebirth of Tanha, Raga and Arati, instead
these same daughters Tanha, Raga and Arati are also our companion; meaning, his three daughters are tasked to become obstacles to enlightenment to us as well.

This is why we must constantly be mindful of our thoughts to see the play of Mara’s three daughters and constantly debate with them with wisdom.so mindfulness and awareness is a skill we are often encouraged to develop on our spiritual path.